# why do i get stuck extracting data from this log data using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a log data file which I'm trying to extract this information from

**example = {"host":"146.204.224.152",
"user_name":"feest6811",
"time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
"request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}**

**sample = '146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'**

when I tried to pull out I got [] empty list

`re.findall('(\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}( - )([\w]*)(\[.*\]))',sample)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. However, based on the example you have given, I have fixed your regex.

Fixed regex: `(\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3})\s*\-\s*(\w+)\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+\"(.*?)\"`

You can check online working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/iOHmqB/1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex has a number of issues, mainly that the pattern doesn't actually match the input.  This is the case because you are missing whitespace in a few places, and also you don't match the double quoted term properly.  Try this version:

```
sample = '146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'
parts = re.findall(r'^(\d{3}(?:\.\d{3}){3}) - (\S+) \[(.*?)\] "(.*?)".*$', sample)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
[('146.204.224.152', 'feest6811', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whitespace was incorrect.  Here's a version that generates the dict example:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

example = {"host":"146.204.224.152", "user_name":"feest6811", "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700", "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
sample = '146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'
m = re.match(r'(?P<host>\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}) - (?P<user_name>\w*) \[(?P<time>.*?)\] \"(?P<request>.*?)\"',sample)
assert example == m.groupdict()
pprint(m.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152',
 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1',
 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
 'user_name': 'feest6811'}
```